# Firebase request range of rows

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm storing user's `lat, lng, timestamp` for every minute.
I want to read only portion of data based on `timestamp`. I've tried below query, didn't work. Also check the attachment of my sample database.

[image]

```
function queryLocations(){  
var ref = firebase.database()
                  .ref('user-locations/' + currentUID)
                  .orderByChild('timestamp')
                  .startAt('1501061958000')
                  .endAt('1501062154000')
                  .on("child_added",function(data){
                       c = c+1;
                       locationCountElement.textContent = '' + c;
                  });
firebaseLocRef = ref;
}
```

So, I've `startTimestamp` and `endTimestamp` as input. I need only rows with `timestamp` between `startTimestamp` and `endTimestamp`.

My firebase rules look like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "user-locations":{
      "$uid": {
         ".indexOn": "timestamp"
       }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `startAt()` and `endAt()`:

```
var query = firebase.database()
                    .ref('user-locations/' + currentUID)
                    .orderByChild('timestamp')
                    .startAt(startTimestamp)
                    .endAt(endTimestamp)
                    .on("child_added", function(data) {
```

**Update**: in your updated code you pass the timestamps as strings. But in the database they're stored as numbers, so you must also use numbers in the query:

```
              .startAt(1501061958000)
              .endAt(1501062154000)
```

Comment: I've tried this. No luck. Please check my updated question.

Comment: How do I index the timestamp? Firebase query needs it to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

It has a good overview of how to read from the database.

In essence, you will take a snapshot of the DB, and search for all entries with a certain timestamp.

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('location_to_timestamp' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  for i in snapshot.val()
     var TS = snapshot.val()[i].timestamp
     if(TS >= startTimestamp && TS <= endTimeStamp) {
       //do stuff to process snapshot.val()[i]
     } 
});
```

Comment: While this may give the result you want, it reads all data from the database and performs the filtering client-side. At best this will be sub-optimal, but at worst it may be wasting a lot of the user's bandwidth.

Comment: This is just querying all the data and manually filtering. This take some minutes of time to read database and waste of bandwidth.